# How reward / penalty is comprehended?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

Technically brain is composed of billions of neurons for abstract computation of the world around us. I am bit confused that how does emotions such as fear/anger gets simulated by amygdala, which is nothing more then bunch of specialized neurons but we feel it as penalty. What part of the brain senses response from amygdala and determines ok, thats fear/penalty? What exactly is penalty?

How does human comprehend reward and penalty (fear/anger/sorrow)?

Comment: you might get a better response here https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user438383 but I am looking for associative answer, so psychology will only provide higher lever behavioral response instead of lower level response based on synaptic aggregation

Comment: The site is Psych & Neuroscience, not just psych, but the question you are asking doesn't have great neuroscientific/biological answers. I'd situate it as part of the "hard problem" of consciousness. There are several relevant Q&As at psych & neuro.

Comment: @BryanKrause I see, i thought there might be tangible answer for example, "fear causes incoherent/abnormal synaptic actuation patterns, which is anomaly and we sense anomaly as negative" just a speculation.  Well this also makes me hypothesize that signals firing that are coherent could be sensed as positivity/reward, we associate beauty with say symmetry face so signals are quite coherent when you experience symmetric face and we associate that to positive/reward. Again just a far fetched speculation.

Comment: @gfdsal There is no reason that "abnormal" or "coherent" patterns of activity are "good" or "bad" any more than activity in a particular brain area. If your speculations were true you'd still be left with the exact same question.

Comment: @BryanKrause allright makes sense, I just made a speculation based on lie detector test, where if one lies the body responses are different from nominal in-other words "abnormal"

Comment: @gfdsal Lie detector tests are pretty poor, but they work on the principle that people are more nervous when they lie, which increases their skin conductivity as they produce sweat. Not really an abnormal response, but a completely normal one in response to stress. One of the reasons they are so poor is because indeed, answering questions in a scary environment can also make people nervous.